# What does an underscore in front of an import statement mean?

Tags: go, import

In [this code](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/_example/simple/simple.go) from go-sqlite3:

```
import (
        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
        "log"
        "os"
)
```

what does the underscore in the `import` statement mean?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

It's for importing a package solely for its side-effects.

From [the Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

> To import a package solely for its side-effects (initialization), use the [blank](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) identifier as explicit package name:
>
> ```golang
> import _ "lib/math"
> ```

#### In sqlite3

In the case of [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/sqlite3.go), the underscore import is used for the side-effect of registering the `sqlite3` driver as a database driver in the `init()` function, without importing any other functions:

```
sql.Register("sqlite3", &SQLiteDriver{})
```

Once it's registered in this way, sqlite3 can be used with the standard library's `sql` interface in your code like in the example:

```
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./foo.db")
```

Answer (score 64):

While other answers described it completely, for "Show me The Code" people, this basically means: create package-level variables and execute the `init` function of that package.

And (if any) the hierarchy of package-level variables & `init` functions of packages that, this package has imported.

The only side effect that a package can make, without being actually called, is by creating package-level variables (public or private) and inside it's `init` function.

*Note*: There is a trick to run a function before even `init` function. We can use package-level variables for this by initializing them using that function.

```
func theVeryFirstFunction() int {
    log.Println("theVeryFirstFunction")
    return 6
}

var (
    Num = theVeryFirstFunction()
)

func init() { log.Println("init", Num) }
```

Answer (score 23):

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank

It's either a work in progress, or imported for side effects.  In this case, I believe it's for the side effects, as described in the doc.

Comment: Here's a link to the [Import for side effect](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_import) anchor on that page. It explains, "sometimes it is useful to import a package only for its side effects, without any explicit use", and "To import the package only for its side effects, rename the package to the blank identifier".

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have an Animal package. And your main file wants to use that Animal package to call a method called Speak but there are many different types of animals and each animal implemented their own common Talk method. So let's say you want to call a method Speak implemented in the Animal's package which internally calls Talk method implemented in each of the animal's package. So in this case you just want to do an import _ "dog" which will actually call the init method defined inside the dog package which actually registers a Talk method with the Animal package which it too imports.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm new in Go, this definition made it more clear:

> Underscore is a special character in Go which acts as null container. Since we are importing a package but not using it, Go compiler will complain about it. To avoid that, we are storing reference of that package into _ and Go compiler will simply ignore it.
> Aliasing a package with an underscore which seems to do nothing is quite useful sometimes when you want to initialize a package but not use it.

[Link](https://medium.com/rungo/everything-you-need-to-know-about-packages-in-go-b8bac62b74cc)