# Golang: generating core failed: unable to load github.com

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I installed golang and started with this tutorial: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-go/1-getting-started/

When I run:

```
go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
```

I get:

```
reloading module info
generating core failed: unable to load github.com/my-user/hackernews/graph/model - make sure you're using an import path to a package that exists
exit status 1
```

What is wrong with my setup?
This is my gopath

```
/Users/my-pc-user/go
```

Comment: have you installed the module?  something like `go install github.com/99designs/gqlgen`. Or used go get, outside a module so that its fetched into you default gopath.

Comment: Yes, I installed it, and also the init worked. It seems it's unable to load my own local project (named it with github.com)

Comment: init would always work. It just creates a go mod. but this generator tries to use a module and that module needs to be in your system. Did you add `$HOME/go/bin` to your path? Althogh usually compiled binaries with go install end up there. I think this one needs to be in src.

Comment: if you have installed it can use use it as binary? `gqlgen generate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

```sh
$ cd your_project_path/
$ print '// +build tools\npackage tools\nimport _ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen"' | gofmt > ./tools.go
$ echo 'package model' | gofmt > ./graph/model/doc.go
$ go get .
```

### Explanation

According to [a quick start guide](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen#quick-start), you should create a package with generated code that actually is already imported by your server:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler"
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/playground"
    "your_module_name/graph"
    "your_module_name/graph/generated"
)
```

Because of the fact that `your_module_name/graph/generated` has no `*.go` files you cannot start a server and if you try you will get an error like:

```sh
graph/schema.resolvers.go:10:2: no required module provides package your_module_name/graph/generated; to add it:
```

To generate that package you will need to execute `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate`, but there is another problem: `gqlgen` generates code that uses another package that is still doesn't exist yet, i.e. `your_module_name/graph/model`.

Additional step adding `build` constraints is required to not drop `indirect` dependency while generation process. That's why there is the first step [with underscore import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225073).

And if you put any `*.go` file to that directory with `package` directive — everything should works now:

```sh
$ cd your_project_path/
$ print '// +build tools\npackage tools\nimport _ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen"' | gofmt > ./tools.go
$ echo 'package model' | gofmt > ./graph/model/doc.go
$ go get .
```